# Getting ASK price on Bloomberg using Python API

Tags: python, excel-2010, bloomberg, datanitro, blpapi

I am trying to get the ASK price from Bloomberg using Excel's DataNitro.

I am calling this function from excel:

main()

```
def main():
    options = parseCmdLine()

    # Fill SessionOptions
    sessionOptions = blpapi.SessionOptions()
    sessionOptions.setServerHost(options.host)
    sessionOptions.setServerPort(options.port)


    # Create a Session
    session = blpapi.Session(sessionOptions)

    # Start a Session
    if not session.start():

        return "Failed to start session."

    try:
        # Open service to get historical data from
        if not session.openService("//blp/refdata"):

            return "Failed to open //blp/refdata"

        sendIntradayBarRequest(session, options)

        # wait for events from session.
        askPrice=eventLoop(session)
        return "Ask Price: %s " % (askPrice)

    finally:
        # Stop the session
        session.stop()
```

On Excel:
return "Ask Price: %s " % (askPrice)
it always says "Python timeout" on the cell I'm calling the function from

however when I change the return to print, it correctly shows the price on the Python shell
print "Ask Price: %s " % (askPrice)

Is the problem on Bloomberg's side regarding making a session which I have to contact them or on the actual code that I have to fix? Any advice?

Comment: is `askPrice` possibly recursive in nature?  Maybe python gets stuck in a recursive loop when converting it to a string but doesn't raise a recursion error because the code is handled in C...

Answer (score 0):

How long does the price take to return? DataNitro UDF's time out after 3 seconds to prevent long-running functions from freezing Excel. You can modify the timeout duration in DataNitro's Settings.

Comment: I even changed the time out to 30 seconds, and still not working. It's usually fast when I am running on the Python shell

Comment: This seems more fitting for a comment then an answer.